# INSERT with transaction and parameters?

Tags: vb.net, parameters, insert, transactions, system.data.sqlite

I'm learning about VB.Net and need to work with an SQLite database using the open-source System.Data.SQLite ADO.Net solution

The examples I found in the HOWTO section are only in C#. Would someone have a simple example in VB.Net that I could study to understand how to use transactions when INSERTing multiple parameters?

FWIW, here's the code I'm working on:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
    Dim SQLcommand As SQLite.SQLiteCommand
    Dim SQLtransaction As SQLite.SQLiteTransaction

    SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=test.sqlite;"
    SQLconnect.Open()

    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

    SQLcommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, hash TEXT);"
    SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        '================ INSERT starts here
    SQLtransaction = SQLconnect.BeginTransaction()
    Dim myparam As New SQLite.SQLiteParameter()

    SQLcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [files] ([name],[hash]) VALUES(?,?)"

    SQLcommand.Parameters.Add(myparam)

    'How to set all parameters? myparam.Value

    SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SQLtransaction.Commit()
        '================ INSERT ends here

    SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT id,name,hash FROM files"
    'How to tell if at least one row?
    Dim SQLreader As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()
    While SQLreader.Read()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(SQLreader(1))
    End While

    SQLcommand.Dispose()
    SQLconnect.Close()
End Sub
```

Thank you.

---

Edit: For those interested, here's some working code:

```
SQLtransaction = SQLconnect.BeginTransaction()
SQLcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO files (name,hash) VALUES(@name,@hash)"
SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "myfile")
SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", "123456789")
SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLtransaction.Commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction approach should be the same (providing the SQLite API supports transactions.)  As for multiple parameters, you need to declare a SqlParameter class instance for each parameter, then add each one to the query.

```
Dim myparam As New SQLite.SQLiteParameter()
myparam.Value = "Parameter 1's value"

Dim myparam2 As New SQLite.SQLiteParameter()
myparam2.Value = "Parameter 2's value"

SQLcommand.Parameters.Add(myparam)
SQLcommand.Parameters.Add(myparam2)
```

As for your question "How to tell if at least one row" the standard .NET SQLReader's have a "HasRows" property.  i.e.

```
If SQLreader.HasRows Then
    While SQLreader.Read()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(SQLreader(1))
    End While
End If
```

I presume the SQLlite driver should as well.

Sorry if this code isn't clean VB, I haven't touched it in about 5 years!

Comment: Thanks guys. I found a sample that used SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue() to add items to a prepared query.

Comment: Ah good to know, I've always done "SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(name, value));" - I can save myself a bit of typing - thanks :)